# Handling and Reading popup using selenium web driver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver in C#. I have following window:

Reset Window

[image]

when I click on Update button using selenium webdriver, I get the following popup:

popup on reset window

[image]

I tried following code but it is not working:

```
 IAlert alert = driverFF.SwitchTo().Alert();
```

and also I tried this too but it is not working too:

```
 IAlert alert = driverFF.SwitchTo().window(handle); //I don't know handle of popup too
```

I want to read the text of popup as a string or text message and store it in a variable.
Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Seems more tooltip than popup. Check how this element presented in code. I bet it is simple div with text.

Comment: @Somber Can you guide how to check this element in code? and if it so, then simple tools like "inspect element" can help me or not? Problem is that this tool tip or popup disappears as soon as there is a click on outside of thispopup.

Comment: right click on this object and view this element in code or whatever it works in your browser
or copy text and run search in page source by it

Comment: Can some one else contribute in this question? I am still unable to find the answer.